# Bayesian Stats: Posterior Probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have a question on the definition of posterior probability as defined on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Definition):

a)
$$
p(\theta|x) = \frac{p(x|\theta)}{p(x)}p(\theta)
$$
where $p(x)$ is the normalizing constant and is calculated as

b)
$$
p(x) = \int p(x|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta
$$
for continuous $\theta$,
or by summing $p(x|\theta)p(\theta)$
over all possible values of $\theta$ for discrete $\theta$
$$

**Question**
How is (b) derived from (a)?  I get:
$$
p(x) = \frac {p(x \cap \theta) p(\theta) p(x)} {p(\theta) p(x \cap \theta)} = p(x|\theta) \frac {p(\theta)}{p(\theta|x)}
$$

I'm confused how this equals the integral (b).

Comment: For the continuous case, $p(\theta|x)$ is by definition a probability density function in $\theta$, so it must integrate to $1$. Just integrate both sides of the equation in (a) w.r.t. $\theta$ and use that fact. (Similarly in the discrete case, summing instead of integrating.)

Comment: b) is not *derived* from a).  It is the definition of $p(x)$.  Every book on Bayes derives this (including ***Pattern classification***, 2nd ed., by Duda, Hart, and Stork).

Comment: Adding on to the previous comments, you cannot derive b from a. Doing this does not take into account that the integral of the density must equal 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is the definition of law of total probability for random variables. Note that $p(x|\theta)p(\theta)=p(x,\theta)$, the joint distribution. Integrating out $\theta$ leaves us with just $\int_\Omega p(x,\theta)d\theta=p(x)$ if $\theta$ is continuous and $\sum_\Omega p(x,\theta)=p(x)$ if $\theta$ is discrete with $\Omega$ the parameter space.

Comment: Notation question: is the joint distribution also described as follows $p(x, \theta) = r_{X,Y}(x, \theta) = P(X = x, Y = \theta)$?  Is the LOTP for JD as $p(x) = \int_{\Omega} P(x | X = \theta) f_X(\theta) dx = \int_{\Omega} p(x)$?

Comment: Yes, you can write it as the product of conditional and the marginal or the joint.

Comment: The OP uses $p(x)$ to denote which I think is the PDF or PMF of a random variable.  Is this true?  This notation is new to me, I have usually seen $\rho_X(a), P(X = a | Y = y), or f_{X|Y=y}(x)$.   Do you know if the following substitution is valid: $p(\theta|X) = f_{\theta|X =  x}(t)$?